# WordPress function is_user_logged_in is not working in siteurl, wp_redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I was trying to modify **site_URL** and **wp_redirect** with the following code

```php
<?php

add_filter( 'site_url', 'my_prefix_site_url', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wp_redirect', 'my_prefix_wp_redirect' );

function my_prefix_site_url( $url, $scheme ) {
    return my_prefix_modify_url( $url, $scheme );
}

function my_prefix_wp_redirect( $url ) {
    return my_prefix_modify_url( $url, null );
}

function my_prefix_modify_url( $url, $scheme = null ) {
    $current_url = isset( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslush( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ) ) : '';

    if ( ! strpos( $current_url, 'wp-admin' ) && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return '/';
    }

    return $url;
}
```

But got the following error.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function **is_user_logged_in()**

After some research I figured out that **wp_redirect** is called before the **pluggable.php** file is called which contains **is_user_logged_in()** function. So I went on to include it in my code as following

```php
if ( ! function_exists( 'is_user_logged_in' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php';
}
```

After including this file, the code is working properly but some other plugins are conflicting with it, as they are not able overwrite the pluggable functions.

**Short Question**: How can I validate if user is logged in at **wp_redirect** level before pluggable.php is loaded.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try the `template_redirect` hook instead, I think that executes later.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your response but we do not have access for template redirect at wp-admin

Comment: Not sure what that is supposed to mean. Or what you are even actually trying to achieve here - can you give a proper explanation of that first of all, please?

Comment: You know that `wp_redirect` is used by a whole lot of things, right? For instance, when you have permalinks enabled and visit `example.com/about`, WordPress will use that function to send people to `example.com/about/`. If I'm reading your code correctly, your filter would redirect that to `example.com/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't understand what this code's actual purpose is, and I can think of several things it would break if I'm reading it correctly, but to your literal question: just write your own function.

The function [`is_user_logged_in`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) isn't very complicated in the default version:

```php
function is_user_logged_in() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    return $user->exists();
}
```

And [`wp_get_current_user`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/) is also pluggable but simple:

```php
function wp_get_current_user() {
    return _wp_get_current_user();
}
```

So you'd just write this:

```php
function custom_is_user_logged_in() {
    return _wp_get_current_user()->exists();
}
```